# Need help for phpunit tests on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, phpunit

I’m trying to setup phpunit tests on Wordpress but I can only find documentation for setting up tests for individual plug-ins which install stock Wordpress and creates a new database.

I’m looking to test my entire Wordpress website which involves several custom plug-ins I’ve made which are interdependent and have their own configurations stored on the database.

Can anyone point me to documentation to setup phpunit tests that doesn’t erase the database, and just copies or mocks it for the tests?

Thank you.

I’ve tried documentations that setup phpunit tests for individual plug-ins and stock Wordpress.